# Write a new line character without creating a new line

Tags: python, python-2.7, newline

I have a program that needs to write a little bash script to the `/tmp` directory that will prompt for credentials:

```
linux_prompt_script = (
    'printf "Proxy authentication failed.\n"'
    '\nread -s -p "Enter Password to try again: " mypassword'
    '\nprintf "Proxy authentication succeeded\n'
)
```

When I write it right now it looks like this when `cat`'ed:

```
printf "Proxy authentication failed.
"
read -s -p "Enter Password to try again: " mypassword
printf "Proxy authentication succeeded
```

This obviously isn't going to work. Is there a way I can write a newline character `\n` without creating a new line, and also write it to create a new line?

What I have so far:

```
linux_prompt_script = (
    'printf "Proxy authentication failed.\n"'
    '\nread -s -p "Enter Password to try again: " mypassword'
    '\nprintf "Proxy authentication succeeded\n'
)


def _prompt_linux():

    def _rand_filename(chars=string.ascii_letters):
        retval = set()
        for _ in range(0, 6):
            retval.add(random.choice(chars))
        return ''.join(list(retval))

    filename = _rand_filename()
    filepath = "/tmp/{}.sh".format(filename)
    while True:
        with open(filepath, "a+") as sh:
            sh.write(linux_prompt_script)
```

Comment: just escape backslash like `\\n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A raw string will be useful here. The `r` prefix before the quotes denotes a raw string, which prevents the escape characters being processed:

```
linux_prompt_script = r'''
printf "Proxy authentication failed.\n"
read -s -p "Enter Password to try again: " mypassword
printf "Proxy authentication succeeded"
'''

with open(filepath, "a+") as sh:
    sh.write(linux_prompt_script)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put your multiline text inside triple quotes:

```
text='''
printf "Proxy authentication failed.
read -s -p "Enter Password to try again: " mypassword
printf "Proxy authentication succeeded
'''
```

So you don't have to mind about `\n` at the end of every line.

Comment: The `\n` inside the string given to `printf` should still be there, since it appears to be the desired formatting of the bash script output